# In our RabbitMQ setup, using federated exchanges, I see a a redundant queue which is piling up messages. What is the reason?

Tags: rabbitmq

We have the following setup:

[image: RabbitMQ Setup]

Now, on the Upstream side, I see two connections to the Cluster. One to *rabbitmq-1* and one to *rabbitmq-2*.

The one to *rabbitmq-1* is piling up messages. Note the message count of 413'584.

[image: Situation on the Upstream]

In the downstream, on the Cluster, I see only the connection to *rabbitmq-2*.

[image: Situation on the Downstream]

If I delete the queue to *rabbitmq-1* it reappears after some time.

Why are there two queues, and why is the one to *rabbitmq-1* not processing any messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This happens in the following case:**

1. Your cluster has no name defined. In such case the name of the node is used as a cluster name.
2. Your cluster is behind a load balancer which selects node randomly.
3. You use the load balancer url to setup the federation upstream. In such case when the node restarts. The connection from another node is made which has different name.

**Solution**

The easiest solution is to set the cluster name on any node in the cluster with the following command.

```
rabbitmqctl set_cluster_name "rabbitmq-cluster"
```

After that all nodes in the cluster will return the same name and no redundant exchanges or queues will be created